# Mongoosejs Validation Errors

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm unable to get my data to go into my MongoDB collection. It gives me this message:
[image]

Here's the Schema. I'm able to make GET, PATCH, AND DELETE work but not POST. I've tried looking up the answers in regards to this issue, however, the support doesn't look stellar. I

````
const IssueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  projectTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'must provide project title'],
    trim: true,
    maxLength: [30, 'project name cannot be more than 30 characters']
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'must provide a succinct description of the project'],
    trim: true,
    maxLength: [120, 'project description cannot be more than 120 characters']
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  issueTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'must provide issue title'],
    trim: true,
    maxLength: [30, 'project name cannot be more than 30 characters']
  },
  priority: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ['low', 'normal', 'important', 'critical'],
      message: `{VALUE} is not supported`
    }
  },
  issuer: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ['Admin', 'Lead', 'QA'],
      message: `{VALUE} is not supported`
    }
  },
  developer: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ['Jason W.', 'Ada L.', 'Alan T.'],
      message: `{VALUE} is not supported`
    }
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      values: ['open', 'closed'],
      message: `{VALUE} is not supported`
    }
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Issue', IssueSchema)```
````

Comment: Well, it looks like the object is not being fully passed to the model. The request type ('POST', 'PATCH') does not matter. What only matters is that all of your required properties are being sent. Looks like you need to trace and debug your code and see why all required properties are not reaching the model.

Comment: May I know why are you sending the JSON object like { issues : [.....] } like this? Because in schema it is just an object without the issues array

Comment: Anveeg Sinha, you may have been onto something, which is embarrassing! I can't believe I didn't notice that and then I thought you were wrong. Shows what I know! Thanks everyone!